# Content-Security-Policy (CSP) for every page?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I understand the benefits of using CSP, but is it a waste to send those headers for anything other than HTML files? Do I need to send CSP headers on an image, for example? For a `.js` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Content-Security-Policy header only makes sense on HTML pages.

A security header that would make sense for a image or other resource would be Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But that is restrictive by default, so you don't need to do anything with that.